# Deserialize Json Object containing multiple sub Array and Bulk Copy in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have the following JSON data containing multiple sub array, Any suggestion how can Deserialize this and print on my page.

- NEXT STEP

  : After this, I need to insert this data in SQL using bulk copy features.

**C# Code**

```
collect mydata= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<collect >(json);
    foreach (var item in mydata.results)
    {
    context.Response.Write(item.newPrice + item.pName);
    }

 public class collect 
    {
        public List<collection1> results { get; set; }
    }

    public class collection1
    {
        public List<data> collection1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class data
    {
        public string newPrice { get; set; }
        public string pName { get; set; }
    }
```

JSON Array :

```
{
  "name": "Test 1",
  "count": 3,
  "version": 2,
  "lastsuccess": "Thu Oct 09 2014 05:42:17 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "newPrice": "12787",
        "pName": "Sony Xperia M Dual Black"
      },
      {
        "newPrice": "24999",
        "pName": "LG Google Nexus 5 16 GB (Black)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question regarding how to de serialize the JSON here is a solution... I am not sure what you mean by "Print on my page" as your question does not put that into any context however...

I used http://json2csharp.com to create the poco classes below...

```
public class Collection1
{
    public string newPrice { get; set; }
    public string pName { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public List<Collection1> collection1 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public string lastsuccess { get; set; }
    public Results results { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following code will deserialize the JSON to C#...

```
RootObject myData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

You can now do with it as you please, in terms of your bulk insert... thats another question really so please start a new one.

Comment: And how can i print newPrice, pName now.

Comment: foreach (var item in myData.results)
            {
                context.Response.Write(item.newPrice + item.pName);
            } 
is getting error.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, once you have deserialized this class you can do whatever you please with it? How is anyone meant to tell you how to print this if we have not seen your code?

Comment: Sorry, I got it. I should be myData.results.Collection1

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer if it helped you so that it may help others

Comment: I just accepted it, Can you also suggest me for SQL bulk copy